# How to change the response content type for a Dropwizard REST service?

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I took a look at the Dropwizard framework and I want to use it to package my existing REST service.

In the tutorial I noticed that the response content type is not set using a ResponseBuilder, can I set the reponse type like I would do for a regular REST service if it were not in a Dropwizard framework ?

The reason I want to set a dynamic response content type is because the webservice does not know the kind of data it is serving.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just return a `Response` object and adjust the type. For instance:

```java
@Path("/hello")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class Example{

  @GET
  public Response sayHello() {
    return Response.ok("Hello world").type(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).build();
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi Condit thanks, how does the yml file be for this i.e in the case of  returning a Response object?

Comment: How is the YAML file restricting the return type of your service method?

Comment: Hi, I want the response to be as excel file, how can i do that.. i am using apache poi ?